# Shut off circuit when under a certain voltage?

Tags: voltage, batteries, switches, series

I have three batteries wired in series, in order to produce 9v. If one of those batteries dies, I need the whole circuit to shut off. The best solution I've found is to use a comparator, but the problem with that is that it requires a separate 9v source in order to have something to compare the voltage with. However, if this second 9v source dies off, the circuit will **always** let power through, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to shut off a circuit when it goes below a certain voltage?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you look at it from the point of view where you only enable the circuit when its above a certain voltage ... ?

Comment: Even so, how would you do that?

Comment: Consider how 'shut off' you really need it to be. It's not hard to create a reference voltage with a few tens of uA or even less.

Comment: P.S. you don't need to create a 9V reference, in fact that makes things more difficult. You can divide down the variable 9V to something like 2.5V and compare *that* with a 2.5V reference, for example. The divider draws a bit of current too, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use something like an 8.2 volt zener diode to conduct current to the base of a BJT when the supply voltage is about 9 volts. Depending on your load current the BJT may be able to drive the load adequately without further transistors. Two resistors are also required; one in series with the zener to limit base current and one to properly turn off the BJT when volts drop below about 8.5 volts: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQL022.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The combined "blocking voltage" of an 8.2 volt zener and the base emitter junction is about 8.9 volts so round about this figure the base is going to start taking a little current and switching on the load. Given that the BJT will have a gain of around 100, 1mA into the base will yield about 100mA into the load.

If this circuit doesn't quite turn on enough at 9 volts then use a lower value zener possibly padded out with a forward connected diode in series.

A 7.5 volt zener will start to feed about 1mA into the base at a battery voltage of about 8.3 volts. At 9 volts I reckon the base will be taking about 8mA and pretty much saturating the transistor for loads that consume less than a couple of hundred milli amps.

Comment: Nice and simple. +1

Comment: What exactly is a zener diode? I don't understand the wikipedia page.

Comment: @ollien it's like a normal diode - it conducts always in the conventional direction but, when reverse biased (as per the circuit above), will "breakdown" at a pre-determined reverse voltage called the zener voltage or avalanche voltage.

Comment: @Jirka Zener diodes can be quite leaky and still conduct current below their zener voltage. That leaky current, without R2, will flow through the emitter-base region and potentially keep the transistor activated down to lower and less-predictable voltages on the supply. R2 provides a preferred route for leakage current as the voltage falls and "defines" the voltage at which the transistor starts to cut-off less ambiguously.