# Turn off below a certain voltage

Tags: mosfet, low-power, zener, supercapacitor

Hi I have a small Uc taking samples and sending results powered by a simple solar panel and supercap to get it through most of the night. It works but early in the morning when power is just enough to power the Uc it ends up restarting constantly as the voltage fluctuates on the verge.
I would like a simple circuit that is only on after it reaches a safe voltage ~3.2v. I found this article
[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/160460/shut-off-circuit-when-under-a-certain-voltage) but it looks lossy for a battery solution that matters in the UA range. could I do somthing similar with a Mosfet that uses nothing when off and next to nothing when on?

[image]

Comment: You may be able to use a brownout detector IC, as long as it has the appropriate hysteresis or latching mechanism, as an off-the-shelf solution. Or, consider whether you can just spec more supercaps to last the night until the next solar charging time begins.

Comment: Thanks @nanofarad yes I looked at the brownout option first but i left out information to make the question easier to follow. On boot the Uc samples, then sends, then goes into deep sleep for several mins. There is enough power to avoid the brownout but the radio drains enough to drop it below and it crashes before deep sleep. So switching on with enough power to get to sleep is my first preference.

Comment: @nanofarad yes enough caps to ensure it never turns off in theory is sound. However I then have to ensure there is enough power to get through the darkest shortest day of the year to have it stable. Missing a few results a a day is no big deal...

Comment: I wonder if changing Q1 to a MOSFET and changing R1 to something much larger is the best I can hope for 1UA when on would be OK... Fast switch is not important but it would require something crazy like 10 million ohms to get down to 1UA when on.

Comment: @AndrewT How many microamps can you afford? If the voltage supply is too low (below threshold) then I don't suppose it matters to you. If it draws a lot all that means is that it stays well below the threshold. So who cares? But when active, because the voltage is above another threshold (hysteresis), then you must have some specific budget for operation of the circuit. And yes, it could be something that just pulses a capacitor as a "keep alive" thing. But you still need a budget. Do you have one?

Comment: As per above 1UA would be acceptable .  When off further discharge just adds charge time early morning before you hear from it again, but yes less important than power used while on.

Comment: @AndrewT A relaxation oscillator won't consume much current and would be on the order required and can be arranged as a kind of cheap VCO. But it requires a voltage trigger and an SCR (or equivalent) and a separate C, supplying current to an active switch where if the VCO falls below some point the capacitor voltage stays too high and the circuit turns off. What's the active current requirement for the enabled device? Also, there are some really nice, low power MCUs that are cheap and thoroughly well designed with brownout detects in the area you are talking about. May be better than discrete.

Comment: super-cap, zener, fet... hmmm working with those pieces: sounds like zener would be used in series with the load and a mosfets would need to activate a bypass to the zener once zener was overcome.  trouble though is zener diodes arent perfect.  the leak during inactive time might make you need more capacitance anyway and itself cause an annoying brownout problem.

Comment: @jonk, thanks your low power MCU idea has got me thinking that perhaps I am going about this the wrong way. The current MCU sleeps at 7UA, I wonder if I change the order of things so when it gets enough power to boot it goes to sleep rather than immediately trying to send results and voltage back to base. it can then wake every min and check voltage then only when it reaches a certain voltage start using radio to send results back. At such a low sleep current it will continue to charge from the solar panel. So a software rather than hardware fix...

Comment: @AndrewT That's great! Sometimes the better answer is something like that. I don't know enough details of your situation to be sure, but that's the kind of thing that can really help out better than some external circuit. Use the resources you have in a better way rather than create something external. If the current processor cannot quite make the grade, you can search out others with better methods. The MSP430 series is seriously well designed for low power with extremely fast start-up times for is CPU oscillator to minimize times between operation and sleep, which is also important.

Comment: Thank you @jonk I probably should have mentioned the PCB I designed for the MCU included the ability to measure input voltage, its a hang over from the battery version. I will do some testing. and report back.

Comment: Look for a micropower voltage supervisor, many manufacturer do it. Do not even think of a discrete solution, they use techniques that you can't apply with discretes.